# Angular Promise returns undefined in another component

Tags: javascript, angular

this is my `carComponent.ts` it has following method:

```
async Download() {
    try {
      const settings = {
        kit: true,
        tyres: true,
        serviced: false,
      };
      const [kits, tyres] = await Promise.all([
        this.checkKits(
          conf,
          "A",
         100,
          false,
          "My kit"
        ),
        this.checktyres(100, 50, false, 'My tyres'),
      ]);
    
    const checkSvg= [...kits.slice(0, 4), ...tyres, ...kits.slice(4)];
   checkSvg.forEach(({ side, svg }) => {
     console.log(svg); // here it returns all the SVG data; works 100%
   return svg;
    });
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
   
}
```

this is `viewCarsComponent.ts` which is calling above method. But here promise returns undefined so can anyone help please to resolve my issue? I am not sure what am I doing wrong or what I need to do here to resolve.

```
async DisplaySVG() {
 await this.carComponent.Download().then(data =>{
  console.log(data);
  // here it is undefined... 
 }).catch(error =>{
   console.log(error)
 });

  }
```

Thank you

Comment: `Download` doesn't have a return statement in it, so by default its promise resolves to `undefined`. Returning inside a `.forEach` function isn't going to cause `Download` to return anything. What do you want to return?

Comment: I want to return `svg` coming from `pics.ForEach`

Comment: Do you want to return the first svg? The last? An array of all the svgs?

Comment: I want to return array of all svgs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently have no return statement in Download, so it by default the promise resolves to undefined. If you want to return an array of all the kits and tyres, then simply return `checkSvg`:

```
const checkSvg = [...kits.slice(0, 4), ...tyres, ...kits.slice(4)];
return checkSvg;
```

If each of these have a `.svg` property, and you only want those, then create a new array with just the `.svg` properties, and return that:

```
const checkSvg = [...kits.slice(0, 4), ...tyres, ...kits.slice(4)];
const svgsOnly = checkSvg.map(({ svg }) => svg);
return svgsOnly;
```